# How to clear SSH keys from script run as root?

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I want to configure my laptop to clear all my SSH keys from the authentication agent when I close the lid of my laptop.

Clearing the keys can be done by running `ssh-add -D`.  Running a script when closing the lid can be achieved by adding the script to `/etc/pm/sleep.d/`.

However, when I add the command `su work -c "ssh-add -D"` to a script in the directory, I get the error message:

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

How can the command be properly run from a script that is being run as root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in the environment of your script. This can be done by executing

```
declare -p SSH_AUTH_SOCK >~/.ssh-env
```

as part of your login process. The script then has to source this file before it executes `ssh-add`:

```
. ~/.ssh-env
```

Comment: Is the value sensitive at all?  Should you `chmod 600 ~/.ssh-env` it?

Comment: @Sampo No, it isn't. It can probably be determined by other users anyway (depending on the access rights in `/proc`). Just the access to the socket itself should be safe.